# Modifying x-axis parameters when variable is a time series in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot 21 years of precipitation data using the `plot()`. However, there are some graphical parameters that I have not been able to modify, due to the fact that my x-axis is a time series. What I have tried so far has not given me the expected result.

Here is my code

```
LHCOCC<- read.csv("~/LHC_OCC_Rain.csv", header = T)
head(LHCOCC,6)
str(LHCOCC)
Day<-as.Date(LHCOCC$DAY, format="%m/%d/%Y")
plot(Day, LHCOCC$RAIN_HC, type='l')
```

Output of `str(LHCOCC)`

```
data.frame':    7883 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ DAY         : Factor w/ 7883 levels "1/1/1999","1/1/2000",..: 1 243 485 551 573 595 617 639 661 23 ...
 $ RAIN_HC     : num  0.48 0 0 0 0.01 0 0 0 0.01 0 ...
```

Output `plot(Day, LHCOCC$RAIN_HC, type='l')`
[image]

The problems that I have not been able to fix are the following:

- The x-axis starts on 2000, I want it to start in 1999. For that I have tried to change the `xlim= as.Date(c(“01/01/1999”, “01/01/2021”))` but that gives me the following error  `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values`
- Because the x-axis is a time series, I have not been able to reduce the gap between my data and the plot.

Is there a way to make this changes using the `plot()` command when the x-axis is a time series?

Comment: 1) In `xlim= as.Date(etc)` you must also use `format` like when you coerce `DAY` after reading the data in. Or straight `as.Date(c("1999-01-01", "2021-01-01"))`. 2) In the call to `plot` include `xaxt = "n"` to remove the x axis, then call `help('axis')`

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you for your advised. Is this what you mean (sorry I am confused) `plot(Day, LHCOCC$RAIN_HC, type='l', xlim =as.Date(c("1999-01-01", "2021-01-01")), xaxt="n")` with the addition of  `axis(1, at= seq(as.Date(c("1999-01-01", "2021-01-01"))), labels= seq(as.Date(c("1999-01-01", "2021-01-01"))))` but that gives me an error

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(LHCOCC, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas once again thank you for your response. The output of `dput(head(LHCOCC,20))` was pretty large, due to the fact that I have almost 21 years of data. However, my actual data is not important for the exercise, so here is two variables that recreate the timeline `Day<-seq(as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("2020-07-31"), by="days")` and artificial rain `Prce<-runif(7883, min=0, max=7)` 7883 is the number of readings that I have. Please let me know your thoughts and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very difficult to plot dates in the x axis with base R. The main error was in the `seq` command posted in the question but not in the last comment.

**Right**

A `seq` instruction with a `from`, a `to` and a `by` argument.

```
seq(as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-01"), by = "day")
```

**Wrong**

A `seq` instruction with only two arguments, the first being a vector of length 2.

```
seq(as.Date(c("1999-01-01", "2021-01-01")), by = "day")
```

Now, first create a axis labels positions vector. Then plot the data with `xaxt = "n"` in order to suppress the x axis. Finally, the labels are formatted to have only the year. Note that `las = 2` puts labels perpendicular to the axis, remove this if it is not needed.

```
at <- seq(LHCOCC$DAY[1], LHCOCC$DAY[nrow(LHCOCC)], by = "year")
plot(RAIN_HC ~ DAY, data = LHCOCC, type = "l", xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = at, labels = format(at, "%Y"), las = 2)
```

[image]

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)
DAY <- seq(as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-01"), by = "day")
RAIN_HC <- rexp(length(DAY), rate = 2)
LHCOCC <- data.frame(DAY, RAIN_HC)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to decreased/eliminate the gap between the graph and the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your data but here is a small example. Use `plot` with `axes = FALSE` to suppress standard axes. You still have to provide `xlim` to cover the desired range. Then set up the axes separately by using an appropriate sequence. `seq` should work with dates, as well.

```r
plot(1:10, axes = FALSE, xlim = c(0, 10))
axis(1, at = seq(0, 10, by = 2), labels = seq(0, 10, by = 2))
axis(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I am  properly understanding what you are suggesting here is my code  `plot(Day, LHCOCC$RAIN_HC, type='l', axes = FALSE)
axis(1,at=seq(as.Date("01/01/1999"), as.Date("01/01/2021"), by = "years"), labels = seq(as.Date("01/01/1999"), as.Date("01/01/2021"), by = "years")) ` unfortunately that does not fix the problem, because my plot now has no axis

Comment: Also the main issue that I am facing is that I can not treat `xlim` as a regular sequence because I have a time series, daily precipitation measurements from 1999 to 2020. So please correct me if wrong, but your answer does not address this issue, right?